# type mismatch error when attempting to access a sorted list within a dictionary

Tags: excel, list, dictionary, vba

I have two sheets `Lkups` and `dataResponseTimes`. I am reading the data from 
both initially into arrays.

I am then using the function `GetAmbStpMappingsDict` to create a dictionary of sorted lists from the array `AmbSTPLkupArr`.

Sample data from sheet `dataResponseTimes`:

```
| Category   | Code    | Amb             | Incidents | Total (hours) | Mean (min:sec) | 90th centile (min:sec) | HCP incidents | Date       | Processed Date   |
|------------|---------|-----------------|-----------|---------------|----------------|------------------------|---------------|------------|------------------|
| Category 1 | England | England         | 27703     | 18:36:00      | 00:07:55       | 00:13:44               |               | 01/10/2017 | 02/02/2018 07:45 |
| Category 1 | RX9     | East Midlands   | 4588      | 14:47:36      | 00:08:25       | 00:14:52               |               | 01/10/2017 | 02/02/2018 07:45 |
| Category 1 | RYC     | East of England | 0         | 00:00:00      | 00:00:00       | 00:00:00               |               | 01/10/2017 | 02/02/2018 07:45 |
```

Sample data from sheet `Lkups`:

```
| Amb Code | STP                             |
|----------|---------------------------------|
| RYC      | CAMBRIDGESHIRE AND PETERBOROUGH |
| RYC      | HERTFORDSHIRE AND WEST ESSEX    |
| RYC      | MID AND SOUTH ESSEX             |
| RX9      | DERBYSHIRE                      |
| RX9      | HUMBER, COAST AND VALE          |
| ENGLAND  | ENGLAND                         |
```

The idea being I create a structure such that there is a dictionary key e.g. 'RYC' and associated list e.g. Cambridgeshire etc.:

```
| RYC | CAMBRIDGESHIRE AND PETERBOROUGH |
|     | HERTFORDSHIRE AND WEST ESSEX    |
|     | MID AND SOUTH ESSEX             |
```

The code I have written creates the structure but in sub `test` I get the

> Type mismatch (Error 13)

on line:  `Set sList = dict(key)`

The sub `PrintItems`, adapted from an answer by @Thomas Inzina, can print out the contents of the dictionary `dict,` but trying to adapt this to use without a `For Each` loop is leading to the aforementioned error.

I am assuming this is because, without looping the keys, I am attempting to shortcut access the list in some way. Debugging shows that `dict(key)` is returning `empty`.

I don't want to deploy another loop if possible (i.e. of the keys). I have tried changing datatypes for `sList`, which, tbh, I didn't expect to work.

I would like to be able to loop `testArr` and use the value of `testArr(rowIndex, 2)`, the code field from `dataResponseTimes`, to return the list from the dictionary, for that particular `Code`; e.g. If  `testArr(rowIndex, 2)` were `RYC` I want the three items `Cambridgeshire....` as previously described.

The end goal being that I will duplicate each row, in `dataResponseTimes`, the matching number of times, for the same `Code`, as in the list e.g. For `RYC` I will be duplicating the following row 3 times (once for each region in the lookup mapping (`Lkups`).

```
| Category 1 | RYC     | East of England | 0         | 00:00:00      | 00:00:00       | 00:00:00               |               | 01/10/2017 | 02/02/2018 07:45 |
```

So, a shorter route might be simply to access via the `Code`, as a key, the associated `sList.Count`. The original reason for trying to access the actual list values was that I was going to append the list value e.g. `CAMBRIDGESHIRE AND PETERBOROUGH` to the row.

Please could someone help me resolve this?

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    'Tools > references > ms scripting runtime
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("dataResponseTimes")

    Dim dict As Dictionary
    Set dict = GetAmbStpMappingsDict

    Dim testArr()
    testArr = sht.Range("A2:J4").Value

    Dim rowIndex As Long

    For rowIndex = LBound(testArr, 2) To UBound(testArr, 2)

        Dim sList As Variant, stpName As String
        Dim x As Long
        Dim key As Variant
        key = testArr(rowIndex, 2)       'testArr(rowIndex, 2) is a Variant/string

        Set sList = dict(key)             'Error     

        For x = 0 To sList.Count - 1   
            stpName = sList.GetKey(x)
            Debug.Print stpName
        Next

    Next rowIndex

End Sub


Public Function GetAmbStpMappingsDict() As Dictionary

    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim AmbSTPLkupArr As Variant

    AmbSTPLkupArr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Lkups").Range("A2:B7").Value

    Dim rowIndex As Long

    For rowIndex = LBound(AmbSTPLkupArr, 1) To UBound(AmbSTPLkupArr, 1)

        If Not dict.Exists(AmbSTPLkupArr(rowIndex, 1)) Then

            dict.Add AmbSTPLkupArr(rowIndex, 1), CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")
            dict(AmbSTPLkupArr(rowIndex, 1)).Add AmbSTPLkupArr(rowIndex, 2), AmbSTPLkupArr(rowIndex, 1)

        Else

            dict(AmbSTPLkupArr(rowIndex, 1)).Add AmbSTPLkupArr(rowIndex, 2), AmbSTPLkupArr(rowIndex, 1)

        End If

    Next rowIndex

    Set GetAmbStpMappingsDict = dict

End Function

Sub PrintItems(dict As Object)                   'Modified from code by @Thomas Inzina

    Dim sList As Variant, ambTrust As Variant, stpName As String
    Dim x As Long
    For Each ambTrust In dict
        Set sList = dict(ambTrust)
        Debug.Print "Parent Dictionary ambTrust: "; ambTrust
        For x = 0 To sList.Count - 1
            stpName = sList.GetKey(x)            'sList.GetByIndex(x)
            Debug.Print stpName
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Most likely your key doesn't exist. Remember they are case sensitive by default.

Comment: @Rory: I feel like you are probably thinking along the right lines. What is confusing me is I am able to print out the keys which appear for example as RYC. This is the same as the value I am attempting to use to access via Dict("RYC") I believe. Keys are viewed using the PrintItems sub.

Comment: You should probably check for leading/trailing spaces. If you aren't just going to loop through the keys in the dictionary, you should check a key exists before trying to use it.

Comment: The len of each match i.e. no trailing or leading. Frustrating. It fails even with the sample data shown.

Comment: Well I can see in your sample data you have "England" in one sheet and "ENGLAND" in the other, which won't match unless you tell the dictionary to ignore case.

Comment: @Rory. Damn it you are right about that. My bad.

Comment: that plus what looks like an error in my loop logic looks like it will be the answer. I.e. now i have corrected for that i can also see that the testArr(rowIndex,2) is pushing an empty value through during the loop. Many thanks @Rory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit goes to @Rory for correctly identifying the issue.

1) I had failed to spot the difference in case for one item in the lookup table/sheet (`Lkups`) versus the data sheet `dataResponseTimes`. As @Rory states, the keys here are case sensitive. Changing England to ENGLAND; And,

2) Correcting a transcription error for the loop i.e. 
`For rowIndex = LBound(testArr, 1) To UBound(testArr, 1)` not  `For rowIndex = LBound(testArr, 2) To UBound(testArr, 2)` resolved the issue.